# Slider <h3> Texts are Not Responsive for Phone With Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use bootsrap for slider it's responsive for phones but the texture on the picture just goes unvisible in phone mode. Is there any bootstrap code to solve this problem?

```
<div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('img/bg1.png')">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>First Slide</h3>
            <p>This is a description for the first slide.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but your title and your question dont quite match up. Can you please provide images of the issue that is occurring and what you want to happen instead.

Comment: Post all of the relevant code. The `d-none` class will hide text on small screens.

Comment: Seems like 'd-none' and 'd-md-block' classes prevent the responsive. Thanks ZimSysem for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `d-none` from the `carousel-caption` as this will hide it on small screens.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width:640)
  {
      .carousel-caption h3
          { 
             font-size:14px;
           }
  }

<style>
```

Reduce the font-size in small screens